# How to change value of textbox when a checkbox is selected C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, textbox

I have 1 label and 4 checkboxes. What I want to do is when a checkbox is selected I want the price to increase or decrease in the textbox depending on if the checkbox was unchecked or not. I am lost on how I can do that.

label is `TextBlock_Price`

checkboxes are the following: `phScreenRepair, virusRemoval, hardwareRepInstall, softwareInstall`
My code:

```
     public float? MultipleServiceAdder()
    {
        if (phScreenRepair.Checked)
        {
            return 20.00f;
        }
        if (virusRemoval.Checked)
        {
            return 10.00f;
        }
        if (hardwareRepInstall.Checked)
        {
            return 10.00f;
        }
        if (softwareInstall.Checked)
        {
            return 5.00f;
        }
        textBlock_Price.Text = "$0.00";
        return 0f;
    }
```

Comment: You have the checkbox [CheckedChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event. Please don't be lazy and use google.

Comment: Thought the click event would work, CheckStateChanged would be best as there are multiple things that can happen when you click, shift clicks, and more.... @bruno.almeida

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to the checkBox.CheckStateChanged event and change the value of your label or textBox from there. You could also subscribe to the checkBox.Click event, but that would trigger on every click, but there are some clicks like shift click that could be not intended to set off the event.
Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            checkBox1.CheckStateChanged += CheckBox1_CheckStateChanged;
        }

        private void CheckBox1_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Input Changed!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float x=0.00f;
if (phScreenRepair.Checked) x += 20.00f;
if (virusRemoval.Checked) x += 10.00f;
if (hardwareRepInstall.Checked) x += 10.00f;
if (softwareInstall.Checked) x += 5.00f;

textBlock_Price.Text = x.toString();
```

Comment: He was looking for running code that would run once the check box was clicked. Not run the code once a method was called by a timer or other things along those lines.

Comment: @SeanMitchell he can use these lines every where like checkbox_oncheckedChange event!

Comment: That is true, he could actually, have all of them subscribe to the checkbox check state changed event but all run the same method that would change outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I have not tested it.
Pls Call this method on each checkbox's checkedchanged event.

```
float max = 45.0f;  //(20+10+10+5)

public float? MultipleServiceAdder()
{
    float total;
    total = max;
    if (!phScreenRepair.Checked)
    {
         total = total - 20.00f;
    }
    if (!virusRemoval.Checked)
    {
       total =  total - 10.00f;
    }
    if (!hardwareRepInstall.Checked)
    {
        total =  total - 10.00f;
    }
    if (!softwareInstall.Checked)
    {
        total =  total - 5.00f;
    }

   textBlock_Price.Text = total.ToString();
    return total;
    }
```